# Why doesn't this Systemd service run?

Tags: linux, backup, fedora, systemd

I'm trying to run a user service, to backup my documents, before the desktop system shuts down every night.

```
# Needs to be placed in ~/.config/systemd/user/
[Unit]
Description=Backup with restic before shutdown
Before=poweroff.target halt.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/restic backup --verbose --one-file-system --tag systemd.shutdown $BACKUP_EXCLUDES $BACKUP_PATHS
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/restic forget --verbose --tag systemd.shutdown --group-by paths,tags --keep-daily $RETENTION_DAYS --keep-weekly $RETENTION_WEEKS --keep-monthly $RETENTION_MONTHS --keep-yearly $RETENTION_YEARS
EnvironmentFile=%h/.config/restic-backup.conf
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=poweroff.target halt.target
```

It runs if I start it manually:  `systemctl --user start restic-backup.service`

It seems to enable fine: `systemctl --user enable restic-backup.service`
Returns:

```
Created symlink /home/lance/.config/systemd/user/poweroff.target.wants/restic-backup.service → /home/lance/.config/systemd/user/restic-backup.service.
Created symlink /home/lance/.config/systemd/user/halt.target.wants/restic-backup.service → /home/lance/.config/systemd/user/restic-backup.service.
```

...but when I go to the desktop menu & shutdown, the script does not run, the computer just shuts down.

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: You can add `debug` to the kernel command line to enable systemd debugging (many verbose messages written).